# Kali Linux and RTL8812AU

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, devices, usb-device, realtek

Currently I am running into an issue where I can't seem to find a way to identify which WiFi adapter I want to use as my primary in Kali (v 2017.1)

My laptop has a normal PCI WiFi card inside however I have a RTL8812AU USB 3.0 adapter as well. The way I know I'm using my internal is because I can only see the 2.4Ghz broadcast spectrum.

I am using the same Realtek drivers I use on my desktop which works fine, but unsure if there was an error here. It appears under `lsusb`. I am looking for a way to perhaps identify the adapters and choose which one to use. Should both be showing up in `ifconfig` under perhaps wlan0 and wlan1 or something similar?

EDIT:
Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [105b:e049]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Output of driver installation:

```
sudo apt install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms is already the newest version (4.3.21~20170330-0kali1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Output of installing from GitHub:

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/rtl8812au-master# ./install.sh
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-amd64/build M=/root/Downloads/rtl8812au-master  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1052: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: I mean currently I only see wlan0, and the secondary under lsusb. I guess I was wondering if it should work that way, where it displays both modules as such

Comment: Perhaps I need to reinstall the driver?

Comment: I have tried all of those drivers off github before, and fail to compile/install any of them (see newest edit), the only one I've had success with is the `realtek-tl88xxau-dkms` stated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out I did need to fully remove and reinstall the WiFi driver, and now both **do** show up when executing `ifconfig` as `wlan0` and `wlan1` respectively. As well as both appearing in the network-manager GUI (see image).

[image: Working Image]

The steps I took were:

- Uninstalling the driver by running `sudo apt remove realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms` followed by `sudo apt autoremove`
- Installing the driver by running `sudo apt install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms`
- Unplugging and replugging the WiFi adapter in question
- Run `ifconfig` to check for success, there should be an additional WiFi adapter