# (Kali) Can't "make" for RTL8812AU

Tags: kali-linux, compiling, realtek

I'm trying to install the driver RTL8812AU but I get the error log shown below:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-kali1-amd64/build M=/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-amd64'
  CC [M]  /root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
                 from /root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/include/osdep_service.h:343:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  allow_signal(SIGTERM);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/include/osdep_service.h:353:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (signal_pending (current))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/include/osdep_service.h:355:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   flush_signals(current);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-common/scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target '/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-common/Makefile:1529: recipe for target '_module_/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/root/Desktop/rtl8812AU-driver-4.3.22-beta] Error 2
Makefile:145: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-amd64'
Makefile:1705: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I've done

apt-get install linux-headers-4.13.0-kali1-all

and

apt-get install linux-image-4.13.0-kali1-amd64

What did I miss?

Comment: avoid Realtek hw https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: I did not down-vote your question but would have (I think it has enough already). Basically, as others have said: Kali Linux is NOT for n00bs. It is designed for security professionals to run in vm's to do penetration testing. Yes, you might feel l33t for having it installed, but your Linux experience will be a pain, which is sad as ubuntu and mint are really nicely polished distributions. We really want you to enjoy Linux, we are not always diplomatic, sorry!!!!!
If you want to feel l33t and use a distribution easy to use, choose Devuan.

Comment: @BLayer   This question will be asked frequently when installing the `rtl8812au` driver . a lot of sources on github is available but only the [gnab repo is updated](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au) to be compiled on the 4.13 kernel without problem. all the other sources will fail.

Comment: @GAD3R The question was asked by a newb (as self-classified by OP). If it's a question that would actually be useful to non-newbs (experienced users using Kali the way it's meant to) I'd happily remove my dup flag...anyone fit that description here?

Answer (score 2):

You missed the Kali documentation. From https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux: "[Kali] it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc."

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Kali Rolling then you shouldn't need to do this as the drivers for your hardware are in the repository.

[THIS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369045/kali-linux-and-rtl8812au) post deals with the same hardware installation and it should be no harder than

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms
```

You should be able to find this package in the package manager on your desktop.

On a side note, if you are new to Linux then you will probably struggle with Kali as it is more command line oriented than other distros. Web search a Linux tutorial and do a bit of practice......once your card is installed of course.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile [the newest source](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au) including the "Fix for kernel 4.11+"

```
apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
make
make install
modprobe -v 8812au
```

Also the [lwfinger repo](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8812au) provide the newest `rtl8812au` source driver including the *Fix driver for build with kernels up to 4.14* , it can be compiled successfully under the 4.13 kernel.