# Not able to see wifi interface in ifconfig in Kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, networkmanager

I have added a wifi adapter to my Kali linux box but I am not able to see it in ifconfig output.

Linux version

```
root@kali:~# uname -a
Linux kali 4.17.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.17.17-1kali1 (2018-08-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg output

```
root@kali:~# dmesg | grep -i netgear
[    2.418983] usb 1-1: Product: NETGEAR A6200 WiFi Adapter
[    2.418984] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: NETGEAR
```

lsusb output

```
root@kali:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9050 NetGear, Inc. A6200 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43526]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
root@kali:~#
```

iwconfig output

```
root@kali:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

root@kali:~#
```

dkms status

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/rtl8812au-master# dkms status
realtek-rtl88xxau, 5.2.20.2~20180812, 4.17.0-kali3-amd64, x86_64: installed
```

Let me now if you need any other details to check the issue

Comment: Check this Question & Answers :https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406983/kali-cant-make-for-rtl8812au

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed a DKMS driver module package for `realtek-rtl88xxau`, but according to your `lsusb` output, your WiFi adapter does not use a Realtek chip at all, but a Broadcom BCM43526 chip.

According to [Linux-Wireless Wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211), this particular chip is currently unsupported by the open-source drivers at the moment.

Googling for keywords "BCM43526 linux" or "NetGear A6200 linux" indicates this particular WiFi adapter has been problematic for other Linux users too. The only way it has been made to work is with `ndiswrapper` (i.e. a driver wrapper that allows Windows network drivers to be used with Linux).

Unfortunately ndiswrapper won't support WiFi monitor mode, which means a lot of penetration testing tools (= the reason of Kali Linux's existence) will be unusable with it.